# Rails: how to return valid javascript from controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

A have the following action in controller:

```
def new_messages
    @new_msgs = Message.find(:all, order: 'id desc', limit: 12)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

and javascript erb file `'new_messages.js.erb'` that returns to client after `new_messages` action:

```
var data = '';
<% @new_msgs.each do |m| %>
    data += '<tr><td><%= m.user.name %></td><td><%= m.text %></td><td><%= m.created_at %></td></tr>';
<% end %>

$('#messages-table').html('');
$('#messages-table').append(data);
```

Here I just compose rows for new messages and try to append result to my table `'#messages-table'`. But there is the issue: browser gets invalid javascript from server (according to Network -> request -> Response tab in Chrome Developer Tools):

```
var data = '';
    data += '<tr><td>dime</td><td>cowboys from hell
</td><td>2014-01-24 15:11:36 UTC</td></tr>';

$('#messages-table').html('');
$('#messages-table').append(data);
```

Line break in the line #2 causes `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. Is it possible to return javascript as it is in my new_messages.js.erb file? How to avoid such dangerous behavior?

Comment: Why even do it like this? Do more work on the client side, it looks like you're just adding content to a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main advantage of js.erb files is using html templates in it. You should do something like below.

_your_partial.html.erb

```
<% @new_messages.each do |m| %>
<tr><td><%= m.user.name %></td><td><%= m.text %></td><td><%= m.created_at %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

js.erb

```
$('#messages-table').html('');
$('#messages-table').append(<%=j render "your_partial" %>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) or it's alias `j` to escape carriage returns, single and double quotes for JavaScript.

So updating your `new_messages.js.erb` to the following should work:

```
var data = '';
<% @new_msgs.each do |m| %>
    data += '<%= j "<tr><td>#{m.user.name}</td><td>#{m.text}</td><td>#{m.created_at}</td></tr>" %>';
<% end %>

$('#messages-table').html(data);
```

You could also use only `html(data)` instead of `html('')` then `append(data)`.